# Pod install not installing packages

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

i was trying to install a package using `cocoapods` heres the package name `pod 'LocationPickerViewController'`, when i run `pod install` everything works fine saying `Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.`. the problem is i cant find the dependency anywhere in the project file where it was supposed to be. i tried Cleaning the project and build folder i am using `pod version 1.7.5`

Comment: Make sure that you open the _workspace_ file (.xcworkspace) and not the project file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the workspace file.  When you run pod install, if no workspace file exists, then one will be automatically created for you, and you then need to use that file.